# Perl Can't locate object method

Tags: perl

This is my first time working with perl (v5.28.1). I'm getting the error:

```
'Can't locate object method "load" via stepReader (perhaps you forgot to load 'stepReader')'.
```

When I print something in the file it works, but somehow my method can't be found.

I have `stepReader.pm` in a subdirectory called `src`

**

**example.pm**

```
use lib 'src/';
use stepReader;

@ISA = ('stepReader');

my $class = stepReader->load('assets/glasses.STEP');
```

**stepReader.pm**

```
package src::stepReader;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub load {  
    # Variable for file path
    my $filename = @_;
    # Open my file
    open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
        or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

    # Print the file!
    while (my $row = <$fh>) {
        chomp $row;
        print "$row\n";
    }

    return bless {}, shift;
}

print "test if this works!";

1;
```

*Output:*

```
Can't locate object method "load" via package "stepReader" (perhaps you forgot to load "stepReader"?) at example.pm line 6.
test if this works!
```

I suspect this is something easy, but I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The immediate problem is that there is no class called `stepReader` in your code, only `src::stepReader`:

> ```
> package src::stepReader;
> ```

That is, the function is called `src::stepReader::load`, not `stepReader::load`. Change the package declaration to:

```
package stepReader;
```

Also, module names that start with lowercase letters are informally reserved for pragmata. For normal modules the convention is to use an uppercase letter:

```
package StepReader;
```

(and rename the file `StepReader.pm` to match).

---

The parameter unpacking is broken, too:

> ```
>     # Variable for file path
>     my $filename = @_;
> ```

This puts the `@_` array in scalar context, giving the number of elements. You want list assignment instead (with parentheses on the left-hand side), and method calls pass the invocant as an implicit first argument:

```
    my ($class, $filename) = @_;

    ...
    return bless {}, $class;
```

Alternatively:

```
    my $class = shift;
    my ($filename) = @_;
```

or

```
    my $class = shift;
    my $filename = shift;
```

---

You should always start your files with `use strict; use warnings;` or equivalent. It's currently missing from `example.pm`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use lib 'src';
use StepReader;

# This line is not needed, but if it were:
# our @ISA = ('StepReader');
```